# Create a new User when authenticating with Google

Tags: firebase, react-native

How can I create a document user in firebase when I first authenticate or multiple times ???

Example: I choose to authenticate by google, Twitter .... by account abc@gmail.com ... and I want to save to collection "user" with document = User UId (google account).

With the certificate authentication method I don't know how to get the Google User User UID until it's added to the Authentication List.

```
signInWithGoogleAsync = async () => {
    try {

      const { type, accessToken } = await Google.logInAsync({
        iosClientId: '1058889369323-kh44jtru0ar24qu24ebv1bu0ebrgvokd.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
      });

      if (type === 'success') {
        this.setState({ spinner: true });
        const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, accessToken);
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(error => {console.log(error);});

///I know how to do this, authenticate 1 user and put it in the Authentication list when authenticating successfully the first time     

  } else {
        return { cancelled: true };
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return { error: true };
    }
  }
```